# how to select data from android-based sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i'm new in android and i'm trying to develop an app with database. what i want is to have my app read from a database rather then creating it.

i followed the steps from [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

however, after finishing the steps, i realized that i have no way to confirm whether i succeeded in reading from the database.

what i want to do is:

1. read the data and display it in my app
2. write/overwrite some specified data to the database in my app

please help. thanks alot. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the Notepad Tutorial and code provided on Android the website at the following URL.
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

This sample code shows how to read data from a SQLite database & display it on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think below links will help you

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidSQLite.aspx

http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-sqlite-database.html